# Rigging: the left toe's mesh moves along with the right foot

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging

When I move the right bone on my character the left toe's mesh moves along with the right foot.

Comment: It's hard to help you if we know absolutely nothing about your project and how you set up the armature, weights and controls. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene and settings.

Answer (score 0):

Enter weight painting mode, select your brush to subtract and remove the weights from unnecessary parts.